# window.location = "flie.html" work/doesn't work, depends on the input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to do a login screen which after login/sign up is redirecting to another html file.
HTML snippet:

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" id="userName" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>

...

<div class="action">
  <button onclick="check()">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

the weird problem I have is that when I'm giving input (to Email) with '@' charecter, window.location does not redirect to anywhere.
But if my input is just letters then everything is working as expected and I'm being redirected correctly.

Input of: Email: asd
Password: asd

will work and redirect correctly

Input of: Email: asd@asd.com
Password: asd

will work but will not redirect correctly

js function:

```
function check(){
   
    var name= document.getElementById('userName').value;
    var pw = document.getElementById('userPw').value;
    
    var userObjectString = window.localStorage.getItem(userName);
    
    if (!userObjectString) {
        alert('Error on login');
    } else {
        var user = JSON.parse(userObjectString);
        if(name == user.name && pw == user.pw){
            alert('You are logged in.');
            window.location = "./user.html";
        } else {
            alert('Error on login');
        }
    }
```

please ignore bad code writing habbits, but what did I do wrong?
p.s. code is running as expected and reaching window.location as expected. after that, it only depends on the input. changing input type to Text didn't work and actually made it impossible to redirect.

Comment: This button is probably in `form` which reloads the page after submit

Comment: If Konrad is right then you need to call `event.preventDefault()` on the click event  or the form submit event.

Comment: Where does the userName variable come from in this line? var userObjectString = window.localStorage.getItem(userName); I cannot see it getting set to some value, is it because of some typo?